# Change image when is area expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My lack of knowledge brings me here. I found finally way how to swap images.

```js
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');

    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
};


$(function () {
    $('img').click(sourceSwap);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<ul  class="heads nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <a class="odkaz kis" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseKisela" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseKisela" data-parent='#accordeon'>
      <div class="team-members">
        <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
          <img data-alt-src="img/profile/Kisela_t.jpg" src="img/profile/Kisela_b.jpg"  class="xyz img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <a class="odkaz kraus" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseKrausz" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseKrausz" data-parent='#accordeon'>
      <div class="team-members">
        <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
          <img data-alt-src="img/profile/Krausz_t.jpg" src="img/profile/Krausz_b.jpg"  class="xyz img-responsive" alt="">
        </div> 
      </div>
    </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <a class="odkaz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseJancusko" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseJancusko" data-parent='#accordeon'>
      <div class="team-members">
        <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
          <img data-alt-src="img/profile/Jancusko_t.jpg" src="img/profile/Jancusko_b.jpg"  class="xyz img-responsive" alt="">
        </div> 
      </div>
    </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <a class="odkaz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseBerka" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseKisela" data-parent='#accordeon'>
      <div class="team-members">
        <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
          <img data-alt-src="img/profile/Berka_t.jpg" src="img/profile/Berka_b.jpg" name="" role="presentation" class="active img-responsive" alt="">
        </div> 
        </a> 
      </li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="row tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseBerka">
      <div class="hlavy">
        <h4>René Krausz</h4>
        <h5>CEO</h5>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero atque voluptates maiores magnam expedita inventore eaque alias mollitia voluptate corporis harum ut quod quaerat dolorem, illo fugit soluta impedit, maxime.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseKrausz">
      <div class="hlavy">
        <h4>René Krausz</h4>
        <h5>CEO</h5>
        <p>Some text herer</p>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseJancusko">
      <div class="hlavy">
        <h4>Lukáš Jancusko</h4>
        <h5>CEO</h5>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>Changing text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseGrega">
      <div class="hlavy">
        <h4>Tomáš Grega</h4>
        <h5>CEO</h5>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>Another text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseKisela">
      <div class="hlavy">
        <h4>Juraj Kisela</h4>
        <h5>CEO</h5>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I want to change image back, after I click to another image. Just to have only one changed image in a list.

I'm really stuck, What can I do?

Comment: when you check the dev tools the image are changing what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have this sorted out for you now.

Firstly you need to fix your html, there are some tags that are unclosed

Next for each image, you would add another data element
data-src which will hold the original source of the image.
When this tab becomes active then you add a class "active" to the image

When you click a new image, you would then change the src to the data-src attribute on all active images(which would only be the previously active element).

Then you would add the active class to the one you selected and change the source.
Hope this sorts it out for you. Good luck

```
<html>

<body>
<ul  class="heads nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a class="odkaz kis" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseKisela" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseKisela" data-parent='#accordeon'>
            <div class="team-members">
                <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
                    <img data-alt-src="https://placehold.it/350x160" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x150" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="xyz img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a class="odkaz kraus" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseKrausz" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseKrausz" data-parent='#accordeon'>
            <div class="team-members">
                <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
                    <img  data-alt-src="https://placehold.it/350x160" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x150" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="xyz img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a class="odkaz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseJancusko" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseJancusko" data-parent='#accordeon'>
            <div class="team-members">
                <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
                    <img  data-alt-src="https://placehold.it/350x160" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x150" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" name="" role="presentation" class="active img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <a class="odkaz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#collapseBerka" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseKisela" data-parent='#accordeon'>
            <div class="team-members">
                <div class="team-avatar core-foto">
                    <img  data-alt-src="https://placehold.it/350x160" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x150" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" name="" role="presentation" class="active img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
                </div>

        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="row tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseBerka">
        <div class="hlavy">
            <h4>René Krausz</h4>
            <h5>CEO</h5>
            <p>Some text here</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero atque voluptates maiores magnam expedita inventore eaque alias mollitia voluptate corporis harum ut quod quaerat dolorem, illo fugit soluta impedit, maxime.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseKrausz">
        <div class="hlavy">
            <h4>René Krausz</h4>
            <h5>CEO</h5>
            <p>Some text herer</p>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseJancusko">
        <div class="hlavy">
            <h4>Lukáš Jancusko</h4>
            <h5>CEO</h5>
            <p>Some text here</p>
            <p>Changing text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseGrega">
        <div class="hlavy">
            <h4>Tomáš Grega</h4>
            <h5>CEO</h5>
            <p>Some text here</p>
            <p>Another text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="collapseKisela">
        <div class="hlavy">
            <h4>Juraj Kisela</h4>
            <h5>CEO</h5>
            <p>Some text here</p>
            <p>TEXT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var sourceSwap = function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');

            var activeItem = $('.heads img.active');
            var activeSource = activeItem.data('src');
             activeItem.attr('src', activeSource).removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $this.attr('src', newSource);
        };
            $(function () {
                $('.heads').on('click', 'img', sourceSwap);
            });

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
$(function () {
    $('img').each(function(){ 
        this.dataset['original-src'] = this.src 
    }).click(function () {
        var current = this;
        $('img').each(function(){
            this.src = this.dataset[this === current? "alt-src": "original-src"];
        })
    });
});
```

or more that

```
$(function () {
    var current;
    $('img').each(function(){ 
        this.dataset['original-src'] = this.src 
    }).click(function(){
        if(current){
            current.src = current.dataset["original-src"];
        }

        if(current = current === this? null: this){
            current.src = current.dataset["alt-src"];
        }
    });
});
```